# JSON parser with Array Comma Separated Javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays, json, html

i have a JSON structure which looks like this.

```
"content" : {
    "state" : {
      "Idle" : [
        [
          78.366666667,
          1436955825
        ],
        [
          71.281111111,
          1436955840
        ],
        [
          70.41,
          1436955855
        ],
        [
          74.283333333,
          1436955870
        ],
        [
          76.411111111,
          1436955885
        ]
       ] 
        } }
```

What i have to do is to parse this value. i have to separate comma separated value into x and y. i have to parse these values and separate them. i am having problem issue parsing them

it should look like this

```
 "Idle" : [
            {
              "x" : 78.366666667,
              "y" :1436955825
            },
            {
              "x" :71.281111111,
              "y" :1436955840
            },
            {
              "x" :70.41,
              "y" :1436955855
            },
            {
              "x" :74.283333333,
              "y" :1436955870
            },
            {
              "x" :76.411111111,
              "y" :1436955885
            }
           ]
```

Comment: Json is well understood by Javascript. You can get a plain javascript object and then transform it as you want. What is the issues you're facing ? What have you already tried ?

Comment: Any code to show your parsing attempt?

Comment: don't you think second one is invalid. it should be in `{}`.

Comment: @Jai - that would make it invalid

Comment: so you have JSON string or plain object?

Answer (score 3):

Map the `...Idle` elements to objects (see [**MDN**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) for `Array.map`):

```js
test = {
  content: { 
   state: {
     Idle: [
        [
          78.366666667,
          1436955825
        ],
        [
          71.281111111,
          1436955840
        ],
        [
          70.41,
          1436955855
        ],
        [
          74.283333333,
          1436955870
        ],
        [
          76.411111111,
          1436955885
        ]
       ]
   } 
  } 
};


test.content.state.Idle = test.content.state.Idle.map(
                            function (v) {
                              return { x: v[0], y: v[1] };
                            }
                           );

document.querySelector("#result").textContent = JSON.stringify(test, null, " ");
```

```html
<pre id="result"></pre>
```

Comment: Indentation preferences aside, this is the best way to do it. +1 :P

Answer (score 0):

```
var container = {
    "content": {
        "state": {
            "Idle": [
                [
                    78.366666667,
                    1436955825
                ],
                [
                    71.281111111,
                    1436955840
                ],
                [
                    70.41,
                    1436955855
                ],
                [
                    74.283333333,
                    1436955870
                ],
                [
                    76.411111111,
                    1436955885
                ]
            ]
        }
    }
};

var _oldIdle = container.content.state.Idle,
    _newIdle = [];

for (var i = 0; i < _oldIdle.length; i++) {
    _newIdle.push({
        x: _oldIdle[i][0],
        y: _oldIdle[i][1]
    });
}

container.content.state.Idle = _newIdle;
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this way:

```js
var json = {
  "content": {
    "state": {
      "Idle": [
        [
          78.366666667,
          1436955825
        ],
        [
          71.281111111,
          1436955840
        ],
        [
          70.41,
          1436955855
        ],
        [
          74.283333333,
          1436955870
        ],
        [
          76.411111111,
          1436955885
        ]
      ]
    }
  }
};

var newObj = {},
  arr = [];

$.each(json.content.state.Idle, function(i, item) {
  arr.push({x: item[0], y: item[1]});
});
newObj.idle = arr;
console.log(newObj);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: `arr.push({ x: item[0], y: item[1] });`. Don't overcomplicate it.

Comment: Thanks @Cerbrus didn't thought like that. Thanks again.

Answer (score 0):

If you have JSON string you can use [JSON.parse](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON/parse) with `reviver function`

```js
var json = '{"content":{"state":{"Idle":[[78.366666667,1436955825],[71.281111111,1436955840],[70.41,1436955855],[74.283333333,1436955870],[76.411111111,1436955885]]}}}';
var result = JSON.parse(json, function(k, v) {
  if ((v instanceof Array) && (isFinite(Number(k)))) {
    //if array with coordinates - return object instead
    return {
      x: v[0],
      y: v[1]
    };
  }
  return v;
})
console.log(result);
document.getElementById('r').innerHTML = JSON.stringify(result,null,2)
```

```html
<pre id='r'></pre>
```

Answer (score -1):

With [UnderscoreJS](http://underscorejs.org/) is simple:

[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/michelem09/6bfc7ckx/)

```
var values = {
    "content": {
        "state": {
            "Idle": [
                [
                78.366666667,
                1436955825],
                [
                71.281111111,
                1436955840],
                [
                70.41,
                1436955855],
                [
                74.283333333,
                1436955870],
                [
                76.411111111,
                1436955885]
            ]
        }
    }
};

var newValues = _.map(values.content.state.Idle, function (value, key) {
    return {x: value[0], y: value[1]};
});

console.log(newValues);
```

Comment: You don't need a library to map an array.

Comment: I didn't say you need it, I just gave my answer that is correct. Isn't the best one? Well, I can agree, but it's correct. Downvote isn't correct imho.

Comment: @Michelem well that can be done using plain js so why bother to use a lib.

Comment: Downvote tooltip: _"This answer is not useful."_ I think this answer isn't useful because it requires a user to load a library for something that can just as easily be done in native JS. Besides, users can vote how they wish. I didn't have to explain my downvote...

Comment: i am using these values for x and y for Rickshaw graph. but the problem is that the rickshaw is not working as the x has double quotes in it.

Comment: can i create same without using double quotes x